# Having trouble getting VB to calculate

Tags: vb.net, math, visual-studio-2012

I wrote some code to calculate the volume of a sphere.

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub calculate()

        Dim radius As Double
        Dim answer As Double
        Dim newans As Double
        Dim newerr As Double
        Dim finals As Double

        NumericUpDown1.Value = radius
        answer = radius * radius
        newans = answer * radius
        newerr = newans * 4
        finals = newerr / 3

        Label1.Text = finals

    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        calculate()
    End Sub
End Class
```

However, when I click my button to calculate, it always shows "0".

I don't know why it would do this. Could someone help?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code

```
answer = radius * radius
```

and at last you set label text as the answer. But you didn't set values to radius. That why its always been 0.

you should set it as

```
radius = NumericUpDown1.Value
```